# Xamarin.Forms shared PCL project Fails to build, An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

Xamarin.Forms PCL android project has been working fine and I was deploying to emulator to debug successfully. Now it fails to build and I get an "Unexpected error...Reason: An item with the same key has already been added"

When I just build the project, it builds successfully, but when I build by trying to deploy to an emulator, it fails.

This started happening right after I installed a bunch of Android SDK updates to I could test against the newer Android versions. Also installed the HAXM drivers to try and run a faster emulator. Also did some consolidating and updating of NuGet packages. Also changed target from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.

I can successfully start both the older emulator that I was debugging on previously as well as the new one I've added.

Lots of recent changes so I'm not sure which one is the culprit. I need to know how to get some more detailed logging of why the build failed so I can fix it.

Currently the Build Log is set to Diagnostic, but I don't see any specific reason it's failing to build.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit in the Android Options page in the Project Properties.

Under the "Packaging" tab, the "Use Shared Runtime" option was unchecked. As soon as I re-checked this option, I was able to successfully build and deploy again.